# Inputs fields take time to be accessible

Tags: kotlin, android-xml, android-xml-attribute

I am implementing an android app with input fields in kotlin . Sometimes it takes some time to get access to them to make some inputs . The keyword takes some time to display and  when it does't , i cannot exit it when pressing the back button . I dont understand why because a couple weeks ago , everything was fine.
N.B: Note that on some device , it still works without any problem.
I'd like to know what's wrong and how could i solve it ? :

> 

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Cameraphoto"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_lagfo">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/banner_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/banner_register"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo_de_lagfo"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo_de_lagfo"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:text="@string/verif_id"
                android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.12" />
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_70sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_115sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/selfieLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/selfie"
                android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/photo" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_70sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_115sdp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/videoLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/video"
                android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/video_recorder"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/video_recoder" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
    
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_60sdp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01">
    
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/nom"
                    style="@style/InputStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    android:hint="@string/nom"
                    >
                    <!-- champ de saisi -->
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/nomInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        />
    
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
    
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/prenom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:hint="@string/prenom"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    style="@style/InputStyle">
    
                    <!-- champ de saisi -->
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/prenomInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
                <!-- zone de selection -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/civilite"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prenom"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:hint="@string/civilite"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    >
    
                    <!-- champ de saisi -->
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/civiliteInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dateLinear"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dateLabelle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/date_de_naissance"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
    
    
                    <!-- zone de selection -->
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/dateJour"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
                        app:errorEnabled="true"
                        android:hint="jour/mois/année"
                        app:hintTextColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                        >
    
                        <!-- champ de saisi -->
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/dateJourInput"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                            android:inputType="none"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                            />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
    
                    <!-- zone de selection -->
    
    
    
    
                </LinearLayout>
    
    
                <!-- zone de saisi -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dateLabelle"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:hint="Email (optionel)"
                    style="@style/InputStyle"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    >
    
                    <!-- champ de saisi -->
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    
                       />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <!-- zone de saisi -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Email"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    android:hint="mot de passe"
                    style="@style/InputStyle"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    >
    
                    <!-- champ de saisi -->
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:maxLength="6"
                        android:id="@+id/PasswordInput"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    
                       />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <!-- zone de saisi -->
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Password2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:boxStrokeWidth="@dimen/_1sdp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Password"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    android:hint="Confirmation du mot de passe"
                    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                    style="@style/InputStyle">
    
                    <!-- champ de saisi -->
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/Password2Input"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/lagfo_color"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:inputType="numberPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:maxLength="6"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    
                       />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    
    
    
            </LinearLayout>
    
    
        </ScrollView>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```